# javafx stuff, i cant make good titles

Tags: java, javafx

if i made a little program in which i utilized some javafx code,

1. when it is compiled, does the compiler at my java/bin/ compiles the code or
   does javafx compiler compiles it?
2. when a client somewhere runs my program and he doesnt have javafx but has the default jre with him, can he run the whole thing?
3. if he can run it with lets say the latest jre, what if he's using an old jre like 6.5~?

and can anyone recommend a book (latest) about more into javafx? im reading halfway into Rich filthy clients (good book) when i stumbled upon javafx online, do you think its a good idea to drop filthy rich clients and learn javafx because there might be issues about concept differences or something but i might still finish filthy rich clients - a few techniques to learn is always better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers will address [JavaFX 2+](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/), not JavaFX 1.x which worked differently but is now deprecated.

> when it is compiled, does the compiler at my java/bin/ compiles the code or does javafx compiler compiles it?

It is the [javac compiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) which compiles the java code you write for JavaFX.

> when a client somewhere runs my program and he doesnt have javafx but has the default jre with him, can he run the whole thing?

Yes, as long it is Oracle jre1.7u6 or later running on a [JavaFX supported configuration](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html) (eg OSX 10.7, Windows XP/Vista/7, Ubuntu Linux,...).

> if he can run it with lets say the latest jre, what if he's using an old jre like 6.5~?

JavaFX 2.2 + JRE 6 is a supported configuration.  JRE 6 is not bundled with JavaFX, so the JavaFX deployment toolkit will insert code into your application packaging which will provide the user with instructions on installing JavaFX if they want to run your JavaFX 2.2 compliant program.

> can anyone recommend a book (latest) about more into javafx?

JavaFX is currently a fast moving technology, so it is tough for printed books to keep up with the topic.  That said, the books below provide an excellent grounding in the technology:

- [Pro JavaFX 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430268727)
- [JavaFX Introduction by Example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430242574)

[Good online tutorials on the latest JavaFX release](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/) are provided by Oracle.

> do you think its a good idea to drop filthy rich clients and learn javafx

Filthy Rich Clients is an excellent book.  JavaFX generally provides a higher level API for many Java2D animation and graphics concepts.  JavaFX makes heavy use of a retained mode scene graph approach rather than an immediate mode painting approach - so application of many techniques will differ.  However, Filthy Rich Clients provides an excellent grounding in the low level implementation of many concepts which can be generally useful in developing proficiency at producing high quality graphical Java applications.  In the end, it's a question of time - if your short on it, skip Filthy Rich Clients and learn just JavaFX, otherwise I'd advise learning JavaFX and coming back to Filthy Rich Clients to see what else it offers.

Comment: hey thx for the answer i got 1 question tho, you say jfx2.2 + jre6 works does that mean the code must be compiled in a environment with javafx 2.2 installed righr?

Comment: I was talking about the runtime environment for the client, but yes, the compile environment for the developer must have a [javafx 2.2 sdk](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/index.html) installed.